# Applying TDD in an Laravel + React SPA app

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mocha.js, tdd

I am aware that testing libraries such as mocha, chai are widely used in Javscript, but in PHP, phpunit, phpspec are widely used. I am developing a Laravel + React SPA app, which mean it is API based. So I am considering that I use only mocha, chai without phpunit, phpspec. Is it a widely used method? or, should I use phpunit, phpspec?

Comment: are you using front end as separate entity with laravel serving as an rest api(using cors) ?

Comment: No, front and backend are in the same project.

Comment: This is more of a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Anyway, my 2 cents: Why would you not test your PHP logic/output? If you do not test your backend, how are you going to verify your changes in the backend did not break anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to test php specific things with phpunit/phpspec, because it allow you to better test specific happy, alternative or error paths. According to the testing triangle you should write a lot of unit tests (phpunit) and a few acceptance tests (mocha).

[image: Testing triangle]

Let's any an endpoint can optionally sort and filter on 3 values. If you only test the API you should write 16 (4 x 4) tests if you want to test all different scenario's. Using only API based tests, this will take up quite a lot of time. It's better to test those paths at a lower level instead. That way you only have to write 1 test for you API and a few unit tests which are way lighter than the API tests.